# How to validate using argparser in Python using mutually exclusive group

Tags: python, argparse

Below is the example of the command that I have implemented in python using argparser

```
usage: feeder [-h] [--feed FILE] [--flag] [--refresh]
                        [--host FILE | --xmlfile]
                        [--exclude exclude_list| --include include_list]
```

Here is the my python code :

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--feed', required=False, dest = 'feed_file')
    parser.add_argument('--flag', required=False, dest = 'flag', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--refresh', required=False, dest = 'refresh', action='store_true')

    group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group1.add_argument('--host', dest = 'host_file' )
    group1.add_argument('--xmlfile', dest = 'xmlfile', action='store_true')

    group2 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group2.add_argument('--exclude', dest = 'exclude_files', required=False)
    group2.add_argument('--include', dest = 'include_files', required=False)

    args = parser.parse_args()
```

I have two groups as listed above group1 and group2. Now I m looking to create one more group that let me select argument from (feed, flag, refresh, host, xmlfile) or (exclude, include) but not both together.

So that the feeder becomes like

```
usage: feeder [-h] [[--feed FILE] [--flag] [--refresh]   [--host FILE | --xmlfile]]
                   [[--exclude exclude_list| --include include_list]]
```

Any inputs will be helpful.

Thanks !

Comment: Any attempt to make a mutually-exclusive-group from several groups will just end making one big flat group; even if the setup allows it, there's no real nesting of groups.  The usage display is also likely to be messed up.  And that desire usage is hard to decipher.

Comment: For more complex conditions  you need to do your own checking later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use a subparser to add different commands for each of the two mutually exclusive groups:

```
import argparse

# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

# create the parser for the "first" command
parser_1 = subparsers.add_parser('first', help='first help')
parser_1.add_argument('--feed', required=False, dest = 'feed_file')
parser_1.add_argument('--flag', required=False, dest = 'flag', action='store_true')
parser_1.add_argument('--refresh', required=False, dest = 'refresh', action='store_true')

group1 = parser_1.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group1.add_argument('--host', dest = 'host_file' )
group1.add_argument('--xmlfile', dest = 'xmlfile', action='store_true')

# create the parser for the "second" command
parser_2 = subparsers.add_parser('second', help='second help')

group2 = parser_2.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group2.add_argument('--exclude', dest = 'exclude_files', required=False)
group2.add_argument('--include', dest = 'include_files', required=False)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then you will get:

```
$ python3 feeder.py --help
usage: feeder.py [-h] {first,second} ...

positional arguments:
  {first,second}  sub-command help
    first         first help
    second        second help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
```

And for the first command/group:

```
$ python3 feeder.py first --help
usage: feeder.py first [-h] [--feed FEED_FILE] [--flag] [--refresh]
                       [--host HOST_FILE | --xmlfile]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  --feed FEED_FILE
  --flag
  --refresh
  --host HOST_FILE
  --xmlfile
```

And the second command/group:

```
$ python3 feeder.py second --help
usage: feeder.py second [-h]
                        [--exclude EXCLUDE_FILES | --include INCLUDE_FILES]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --exclude EXCLUDE_FILES
  --include INCLUDE_FILES
```